# OpenSwan Dead Peer Detection for Mac WIFI clients

Tags: ipsec, openswan

I am running an OpenSwan server to facilitate client-server connections into a secure data centre.

I have a problem with the standard L2TP over IPSEC client in MacOS, specifically when using WIFI.

When I connect for the first time, it works fine. When I disconnect and try to connect again, it fails at the authentication step (shared secret).

From what I can see, when the MAC is using WIFI, it doesn't get time to send a DELETE signal to OpenSwan, so as far as OpenSwan is concerned the peer still exists. I can see this in the OpenSwan logs:

```
Jun  8 12:23:43 vpn1 pluto[20030]: ERROR: asynchronous network error report on eth0 (sport=500) for message to 213.242.106.82 port 500, complainant 213.242.106.82: Connection refused [errno 111, origin ICMP type 3 code 3 (not authenticated)]
```

This message continues to appear in the OpenSwan logs long after I have disconnected the Mac client. When I restart the ipsec service on the server, the log entry disappears and I can connect again.

I have included dead peer detection in my OpenSwan config:

```
 dpddelay=30
 dpdtimeout=120
 dpdaction=clear
```

I can see that Dead Peer Detection is enabled when I start the connection:

```
Jun  8 12:45:34 vpn1 pluto[11064]: "vpnpsk"[14] 213.242.106.82 #14: STATE_QUICK_R2: IPsec SA established transport mode {ESP/NAT=>0x0188ccda <0x7fe9af15 xfrm=AES_256-HMAC_SHA1 NATOA=none NATD=213.242.106.82:4500 DPD=enabled}
```

However, when I close the connection on the MAC, DPD doesn't seem to kick in. OpenSwan just keeps logging errors about the connection.

Just looking for suggestions re. a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug in the version of OpenSwan I am using.

I am using Amazon Linux AMI and the problem RPM is:

```
 openswan.x86_64 0:2.6.37-3.17.amzn1
```

I downgraded to

```
openswan.x86_64 0:2.6.37-2.16.amzn1
```

and the issue disappeared.

Apparently there are quite a few bugs in 3.17